# How to edit texture's Alpha channel via code, in order to cut a hole in a texture that's covering the screen?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm drawing a texture that's covering my screen, and would like to "cut out" a rectangular hole in its alpha channel via code (in order to reveal the scene behind it) - with variables for adjusting the size and position of the hole. How can I do that?

This is the code I've got that covers the entire screen with a texture:

```
 using UnityEngine;
 
 public class HoleInScreen : MonoBehaviour 
 {
     public Texture2D screenImage;
    
     void OnGUI()
     {
         GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), screenImage);
     }
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your texture supports an alpha channel you could simply do

- Use [`Texture2D.GetPixels`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixels.html) to get pixels in according range
- Set the alpha value for all to `0`
- Use [`Texture2D.SetPixels`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixels.html) to write back the changed pixels

Something like

```
public void CutRectangleHole(Texture2D texture, Vector2Int bottomLeft, Vector2Int topRight)
{
    var size = topRight - bottomLeft;
    var pixels = texture.GetPixels(bottomLeft.x, bottomLeft.y, size.x, size.y, 0);
    for(int i = 0; i < pixels.Length; i++)
    {
        var color = pixels[i];
        color.a = 0;
        pixels[i] = color;
    }

    texture.SetPixels(bottomLeft.x, bottomLeft.y, size.x, size.y, pixels, 0);
    texture.Apply();
}
```

where `bottomLeft` is the bottom left start point of the hole, `topRight` is the top right end point of the hole.

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting this error though: Unsupported GraphicsFormat(97) for SetPixel operations.
UnityEngine.Texture2D:SetPixels(Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Color[], Int32) - I've tried using a texture that's a PNG, PSD, and TGA without any success :(

Comment: Please checkout [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/setpixels-unsupported-texture-format.150028/)

Comment: You rock man! Thanks a lot! (I changed the Format to RGBA 32 bit and that sorted it.)